# EditText control color

Tags: android, material-design

Im trying to change the color of the EditText control (the line) after a user has put in wrong credentials like in googles material design [TextField material design](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-single-line-text-field) although nothing seems to work correctly the closest situation i have is by using

```
passwordEditText.getBackground().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.error_color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
passwordTextInput.setError(errorHelper.getErrorMessage(e));
passwordTextInput.setErrorEnabled(true);`
```

Although this may work but i still have the old color is in the background
[image]

Any Ideas??

Style Used

```
<style name="LoginEditTextTheme" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/login_edit_text_line</item> //black
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@android:color/widget_edittext_dark</item> //black
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@android:color/black</item> //black
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/login_hint</item> //light grey
</style>
```

XML

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/password_textlayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/LoginEditTextTheme">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password_edittext"
                style="@style/LoginEditTextStyle" //no theme here 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/login_password_hint"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:nextFocusDown="@+id/login_button" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Color of line in EditText is that you initialized as android:colorAccent  in theme. Try to change this it will change the color of EditText control line.

Comment: android:colorAccent seems to have no effect, it was a different color from the beginning but i changed it again and nothing...

Comment: please show your style with your code.

Comment: @AnujSharma Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try this method:

```
public static void tintWidget(View view, int color) {
    Drawable wrappedDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(view.getBackground());
    DrawableCompat.setTint(wrappedDrawable, getResources().getColor(color));
    view.setBackgroundDrawable(wrappedDrawable);
}
```

You can just pass the desired color and EditText reference into this helper method and it will color the EditText's bottom line for ya. This relies on the 
appcompat-v7:22.1.0+ library at minimum

Comment: Unfortunately it is the same. i am using 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1', 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'

Comment: hmmm, that is weird. The image you provided makes it appear as if the line has two colors split in the middle black/red

Comment: The black shows cause its the color from the Theme i set. It seems like the colorControlNormal is always active...